# Error in make for OpenSSL with MSYS+MinGW

Tags: c, openssl, mingw, msys

I use msys+MinGW on windows11

Trying to build Openssl-3.1.4

Places the opnessl

```
./Configure mingw
```

and

```
make depend
```

I seems the build process is good so far.
However make stops by following errors

```
gcc -m32 -Wall -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -static-libgcc -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base   -Wl,--out-implib=libcrypto.dll.a \
                -o libcrypto-3.dll libcrypto.def \
                ./libcrypto-shlib-libcrypto.res.obj @libcrypto-3.dll.args \
                providers/libdefault.a providers/libcommon.a  -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcrypt32
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_lbuf.obj:bf_lbuf.c:(.text+0x830): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_nbio.obj:bf_nbio.c:(.text+0x390): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_null.obj:bf_null.c:(.text+0x1c0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_prefix.obj:bf_prefix.c:(.text+0x4d0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_readbuff.obj:bf_readbuff.c:(.text+0x540): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bio_addr.obj:bio_addr.c:(.text+0x480): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bio_cb.obj:bio_cb.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bio_dump.obj:bio_dump.c:(.text+0x250): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bio_lib.obj:bio_lib.c:(.text+0x190): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bio_meth.obj:bio_meth.c:(.text+0xa0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bio_sock.obj:bio_sock.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bio_sock2.obj:bio_sock2.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_acpt.obj:bss_acpt.c:(.text+0xd00): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_bio.obj:bss_bio.c:(.text+0x9c0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_conn.obj:bss_conn.c:(.text+0xef0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_core.obj:bss_core.c:(.text+0x280): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_dgram.obj:bss_dgram.c:(.text+0xb90): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_fd.obj:bss_fd.c:(.text+0x470): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_file.obj:bss_file.c:(.text+0x830): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_log.obj:bss_log.c:(.text+0x300): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_mem.obj:bss_mem.c:(.text+0x950): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_null.obj:bss_null.c:(.text+0x80): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bss_sock.obj:bss_sock.c:(.text+0x380): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-ossl_core_bio.obj:ossl_core_bio.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/cmp/libcrypto-shlib-cmp_client.obj:cmp_client.c:(.text+0x17c0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/conf/libcrypto-shlib-conf_api.obj:conf_api.c:(.text+0x1c0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/conf/libcrypto-shlib-conf_def.obj:conf_def.c:(.text+0x2330): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/conf/libcrypto-shlib-conf_lib.obj:conf_lib.c:(.text+0x60): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/des/libcrypto-shlib-cfb_enc.obj:cfb_enc.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/dh/libcrypto-shlib-dh_kdf.obj:dh_kdf.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/dso/libcrypto-shlib-dso_dlfcn.obj:dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/dso/libcrypto-shlib-dso_win32.obj:dso_win32.c:(.text+0x1520): multiple definition of `__wspi
api_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/ec/curve448/arch_32/libcrypto-shlib-f_impl32.obj:f_impl32.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/ec/curve448/arch_64/libcrypto-shlib-f_impl64.obj:f_impl64.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/ec/libcrypto-shlib-ec_backend.obj:ec_backend.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/encode_decode/libcrypto-shlib-decoder_lib.obj:decoder_lib.c:(.text+0x5f0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/engine/libcrypto-shlib-eng_init.obj:eng_init.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/engine/libcrypto-shlib-eng_lib.obj:eng_lib.c:(.text+0xa0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/engine/libcrypto-shlib-tb_asnmth.obj:tb_asnmth.c:(.text+0xd0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/err/libcrypto-shlib-err.obj:err.c:(.text+0x270): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/http/libcrypto-shlib-http_client.obj:http_client.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-cpuid.obj:cpuid.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-cryptlib.obj:cryptlib.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-dllmain.obj:dllmain.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-getenv.obj:getenv.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-info.obj:info.c:(.text+0x110): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-init.obj:init.c:(.text+0x3b0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-mem.obj:mem.c:(.text+0x140): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-mem_sec.obj:mem_sec.c:(.text+0x860): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-o_dir.obj:o_dir.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-o_fopen.obj:o_fopen.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-o_init.obj:o_init.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-o_str.obj:o_str.c:(.text+0x1c0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/objects/libcrypto-shlib-o_names.obj:o_names.c:(.text+0x2f0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/property/libcrypto-shlib-property_parse.obj:property_parse.c:(.text+0xea0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/rand/libcrypto-shlib-rand_deprecated.obj:rand_deprecated.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/rand/libcrypto-shlib-rand_lib.obj:rand_lib.c:(.text+0x900): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/store/libcrypto-shlib-store_lib.obj:store_lib.c:(.text+0x1a0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/store/libcrypto-shlib-store_result.obj:store_result.c:(.text+0x740): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/ts/libcrypto-shlib-ts_rsp_sign.obj:ts_rsp_sign.c:(.text+0x50): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/ui/libcrypto-shlib-ui_openssl.obj:ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x820): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/x509/libcrypto-shlib-by_dir.obj:by_dir.c:(.text+0xc80): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/x509/libcrypto-shlib-v3_tlsf.obj:v3_tlsf.c:(.text+0x2f0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/x509/libcrypto-shlib-v3_utl.obj:v3_utl.c:(.text+0x1680): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: providers/libdefault.a(libdefault-lib-capabilities.obj):capabilities.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: providers/libdefault.a(libdefault-lib-hkdf.obj):hkdf.c:(.text+0x1590): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: providers/libdefault.a(libdefault-lib-kbkdf.obj):kbkdf.c:(.text+0x10c0): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: providers/libdefault.a(libdefault-lib-tls1_prf.obj):tls1_prf.c:(.text+0xc40): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: providers/libdefault.a(libdefault-lib-x942kdf.obj):x942kdf.c:(.text+0x1200): multiple definition of `__wspiapi_getaddrinfo@16'; crypto/bio/libcrypto-shlib-bf_buff.obj:bf_buff.c:(.text+0xcf0): first defined here
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-getenv.obj:getenv.c:(.text+0x4df): undefined reference to `_malloca'
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-getenv.obj:getenv.c:(.text+0x57c): undefined reference to `_malloca'
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-init.obj:init.c:(.text+0x1b3): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleEx'
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-init.obj:init.c:(.text+0xd84): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleEx'
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-threads_win.obj:threads_win.c:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `InterlockedOr64'
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: crypto/libcrypto-shlib-threads_win.obj:threads_win.c:(.text+0x2e3): undefined reference to `InterlockedOr64'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libcrypto-3.dll] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/src/openssl-3.1.4'
make: *** [build_sw] Error 2
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) ships a prebuilt openssl, I'd use that.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm charging to  build products by my own.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, but their [build scripts](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-openssl/PKGBUILD) are opensource, and you can run them locally if you for some reason don't like their binaries.